# PHP: $_FILES - Why should i restrict specific file types?

Tags: php, file, types, restriction

Today I was surfing around in the internet about how to upload files onto my webserver with a php formular, and somehow **everybody** only allows specific file typs (and restricts all others). For somebody who wants to upload a picture, it is not nice to see that the webpage does not except that file type. What´s the problem with other file types (for example, directly from w3schools.com: only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF are allowed).
Thankx in advance,
VicStudio

Comment: Why would you allow someone to upload a file you're not prepared to handle anyway?

Comment: Depends on the purpose. jpg, jpeg, png and gif are the only image types supported by all browsers, so for an image upload form, why would you support anything else? You can support other types too, if you like, but you would need a specific conversion. Since limiting types is a common scenario, it makes sense that w3schools and other examples show how to do it. You can omit it if you don't want it.

Comment: upload via http (irrespective of server type) allows any file to upload afaik. because it is usually meaningless to process a file without knowing its type, people will usually restrict certain filetypes and max size. also, this is to avoid viruses etc to creep into your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mainly for **security reasons**. Everything in `$_FILES` is coming from the user's browser, so if you do not have strict validation on what you accept, malicious users could upload files that are

- too large — what if someone uploads a 10 GB image?
- have a dangerous file type — what if someone uploads a `.php` file to your server? Game over.
- have an invalid name — what if someone sets the file name to `../../../file.txt`? When you save the file, it could end up in a different directory due to the `../..` in the path. This is called a [Path Traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) vulnerability.

When processing file uploads, you should validate all three of these against a **whitelist**. That is, have a list or range of values that you accept, and discard anything that does not fit those critera.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to upload Profile Picture and the user is trying to upload doc file.
and vice versa. Then File format limitation can be good for your form for your security.